# GAE java cache problems

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, http, caching

I'm developing a Java application in Google App Engine and I have a problem.
I want to be able to control the app DB from the Admin Console but it seems that it is not working properly, when I change data in the DB it is not reflecting on the app, i.e I have a user that I want to lock so I change the value active = "false", I can see the new value in the DB but when the application make another request I get the previous value in return (in JSON format).

I'm assuming that it something with cache so I tried to cancel it both from the JavaScript and from the Java like so:

JavaScript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "cache-control": "'no-cache, max-age=0",
        "Pragma": "no-cache"
    }
});
```

Java:

```
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem, it was not a problem with the cache it was with the Persistence Manager.

I was using 2 instances of the PM and this was the reason for the discrepancies.

Answer (score -1):

You can try configure your server.Assuming apache:

```
# mod_expires directives: 
# enable expires/max-age headers and set default to 0 seconds from last access time
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
# configure ExpiresByType on your specific types, eg ExpiresByType text/css A0

# mod_headers directives:
# send variety of no-cache directives, should cover any quirky clients and gateways
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
# enclose this in <Files> directive for specific file eg <Files *.js>
```

This is a good article on explaining caching for webpages: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: Holle, how can i do it on GAE running java?

Comment: You can go through this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver